# Base path of my website redirect to Index Of

Tags: wordpress, apache, ovh

My website is a Wordpress and it seems to be available only at https://arch-doc.com/www

My configuration on OVH is [image]

On the base path, it show us the Index Of webpage.

Any advice to handle this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "Index Of", what is shown (I get 404 for both https://arch-doc.com/www and https://arch-doc.com/)?  Is WP installed in your `www/` directory, so that the content of your `www/` directory [looks like this](https://build.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/6.2), with an `index.php` file, `wp-content` directory, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web root contains nothing that tells the server what to render, so it falls back on indexing the folder's content.
What we need to change this is a `.htaccess`-file in this directory with rules to rewrite the request to the subdirectory. There's a [article from the WordPress documentation](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/#method-i-without-url-change) that covers this use case and that I'm working from.

Here's the content of the `.htaccess`-file you would put into your web root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?arch-doc.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?arch-doc.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ www/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This should be it. Just refresh your browser (ctrl-F5, to clear your cache just to be safe :) ) and you should be golden.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I just did what you said but it doesn't seem to work (even after refreshing the cache). The base path seems to be a 404 and the website is still open to www/ any idea?

Comment: Can you confirm that still? I've been trying to access the URL you provided and it is constantly giving me 404s, no matter what path I access it with.
Looking at the requests in my browser's devtools I can see tat the rewrite logic is being executed as expected. Have you changed something about the WordPress that's living in the `www/` directory?

Comment: In that case you have to clean the site's cache from the browser entirely (301s are pretty persistent..)
You can use the Network-tab in Firefox's devtools to "Disable Cache" for debugging purposes. It goes away when the view is closed.

Please make sure to go over the [second section][1] in the article as well, since that seems to more closely mirror the setup you are working with, afaict. Overwrite the current `.htaccess`-file in the web root, if necessary.

[1]: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/giving-wordpress-its-own-directory/#method-ii-with-url-change

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my last comment because they were not corresponding to the actual situation, now my base path renders 404, and my www still render the website but without any redirection !

Comment: Were you able to confirm the steps from the second method I linked?  
I suppose one problem we will might be running into is that we haven't afaiu agreed on which domain WP is supposed to be available on. Because ultimately it can't be both, since WP needs to be aware what its base url (read: SITE_URL) to work from is. (There's ostensibly plugins that are supposed to mitigate this, but the one I found is unmaintained.)  
So a config that works for your www.-subdomain won't simultaneously work for URLs without the subdomain, and vice versa.

Comment: Hi, both your comments helped me answered the question, thx for that. I think my issue was .htaccess was missing with a root folder not well configured. Many thanks for u help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want https://arch-doc.com/ and https://www.arch-doc.com/ to display your website. And not https://arch-doc.com/www/

Assuming that your Wordpress is in your folder "www" with files as shown in the image below,to solve your issue you have to define the "Root Folder" ("Dossier racine") to "www" and remove all other redirection.

[image: OVH Wordpress www folder]

#### Modify "Root Folder"

To change the "Root Folder" of "arch-doc.com", follow these steps:

1. Click on the 3 dots at the end of the line "arch-doc.com"

[image: OVH Root Folder change action]

2. Click on "Modify Domain" ("Modifier le domaine")

[image: OVH Modify Domain]

3. Set the Root Folder to "www". Leave the other options as they are

[image]

You should now have this display.
[image]

At this point:

- when you access the URL https://arch-doc.com/ it will redirect to your "www" folder. The site should correctly display the site.
- When you access the URL https://www.arch-doc.com/, a permanent redirection is set and will permanently redirect (301) https://**www**.arch-doc.com/ to https://arch-doc.com/ and thus correctly display your site.
  [image]

For futher information, You can consult the following documentation: [OVH "Index of"](https://help.ovhcloud.com/csm/fr-web-hosting-index-of-diagnosis?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0052563)

I hope this will help you.